# Object1 in the local coordinate system of Object2

Tags: python, coordinates

I am trying to find the coordinates of Object1 in the local coordinates of Object2.  Neither Object1 nor Object2 are the object that the python code is attached to.

I can find the location of the 3D cursor relative to my active object using:
co_find = context_act.matrix_world.inverted() * context.sce.objects['Cube001']

But I do not know how to find the location of Object1 in the local coordinate system of Object2.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the matrix of ob1 in the local space of ob2

```
mwi = ob2.matrix_world.inverted()
m_local2ob2 = mwi * ob1.matrix_world

loc = m_local2ob2.to_translation() # local loc
loc, rot, scale = m_local2ob2.decompose()
```

Comment: batFINGER, Thanks very much for your help. I'm running my script in the game engine. When I move Obj2, then I want to calculate the loc, rot, scale (using your code).   Your code calculates the initial loc, rot, scale, but when I move my Obj2, the loc, rot, scale do not update with the new values.  Obviously there is nothing wrong with your code - I just don;t know how to update the values when my character (ob2) moves.          Do you have any suggestions?   Thanks so much.

Comment: I've found a solution to this second problem.  I've used camera_to_world, which is a bge function.  Seems like bpy functions don't update in the game engine.